# Angular 12 + SSO redirection + Spring boot

Tags: angular, spring, authentication, redirect, single-sign-on

I'm currently adding SSO SAML to my application and I already configured my backend (spring boot) and it's working when I call a webserviece and I'm redirected to SSO site to be authentified.

But when I use my SPA Angluar 12, it goes like this :

- Angular app calls webservices.
- Backend redirects to login page in another site (SSO SAML)
- As my Angular apps wait for a JSON file and not a HTML file, it shows JSON parse error.
  even though the redirection URL was successively detected in the browser.

[image: Network requests]

[image: Parse error]

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Maybe just use a location.href or a window.open or use a normal href? You want to the browser to redirect so doing an ajax call is not the right way.

Comment: Please add some code to your post